# Where can I find the string resources in Android source code?

Tags: android, string, operating-system, resources, system

I'm trying to get my hands on some system string resources in all languages available, where can I find them?

**Edit: I'm searching for the xml files in the source code**

The source code in the SDK doesn't include resources as far as I know and looked.

When I downloaded the Android Source tree, it kept downloading for hours and hours, it was more than 30GB of project data. Where should I start looking in this jungle of data?

Thank you

Edit: 
answered by @zapl he/she gave me the answer I was looking for.
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/strings.xml

Comment: here: http://androidxref.com/

Comment: @pskink I have the source code, but where in the source do I find it?

Comment: tried androidxref.com ?

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/strings.xml ?

Comment: @pskink can you tell me where in androidxref.com can I find the string resources of the system?

Comment: search for `File Path`

Comment: @zapl Thank you, That is exactly the xml files I needed.

Comment: there is btw an overlay mechanism that is used by manufacturers to add to those resources: https://source.android.com/source/add-device#use-resource-overlays e.g. https://github.com/LineageOS/android_vendor_cm/tree/cm-14.1/overlay/common/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values

Comment: @zapl Thank you, but I'm only wanted to get to the string resources of the system, and you got me that. Thank you again.

Comment: @zapl If you post it as an answer to my question, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @zapl I got what I needed here https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can find them by programmatically like,

```
getResources().getString(R.string.yourStringResourse);
```

Comment: I'm not talking about programmatically, but the xml files

Comment: you can go to 

TestApp -> App -> src -> debug -> res -> value -> string .

If you are still unable to get then got o setting -> appearance -> scope and then add scope to string and then check the project structure.